# Adding elements to arralist iteratively-java

Tags: java

I have UIMA object which contains number of files with annotatios

I am iterating over this object and saving the contents in arraylist

```
Iterator Iter = UIMA.iterator();
    while (Iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        FirstName fn = (FirstName) Iter.next();
            String name=fn.getName();//It will return the name 
            vc.add(name); //Adding to arraylist
           System.out.println(name);
         }
         return vc;
```

The problem here is if i print out the names.All expected names printed out perfectly
But the vector contains duplicates like the following

```
For firstfile    
name1 name2 name3
For second file
name1 name2 name3 name12 name22 name23
For 3rd file
name1 name2 name3 name12 name22 name23 name31 name32 name33
```

Why these elements are adding multiple times?

Comment: clear vc at the end of while as vc.clear()

Comment: @PauloDiogo ArrayList it is in the question

Comment: solutions using a clear on vector are wrong, you need to return a different vector it's time the method is called, or you might clear a vector you will be using later

Comment: the main issue is not the ArrayList not being cleared, but the method always working on the same ArrayList instance when it should returns a different one at each call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Iterator Iter = UIMA.iterator();

vc = new ArrayList(); // HERE is where you need to create your vc object
while (Iter.hasNext()) 
{
    FirstName fn = (FirstName) Iter.next();
        String name=fn.getName();//It will return the name 
        vc.add(name);
       System.out.println(name);
     }
     return vc;
```